# Identifying Java String characters either its lower or upper case

Tags: java, string

```
A   123
B   456
a   789
b   091

String str = "A quick BROWN Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog";
```

if a is uppercase then 123 and if a is lowercase then 789;

how to find upper or lower case "a" or "b" in the string and then convert it to number value?

Comment: It's quite easy to solve. Post whatever you have tried so far and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    String str = "A quick BROWN Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog";

    String result = str.replace("A", "123").replace("a", "789").replace("B", "456").replace("b", "091");

    System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

That will output the following:

```
result = 123 quick 456ROWN Fox jumps over the L789zy Dog
```

Comment: If I start with `String str = "A quick BROWN Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog & a Cat";`, then `str.replace("&","&#38").replace("A", "123").replace("a", "789").replace("B", "456").replace("b", "091");` produces `123 quick 456ROWN Fox jumps over the L789zy Dog &#38 789 C789t`.

Comment: Understand that `str.replace("&","&#38")` doesn't change the String.  It creates a new one.  You will want to assign the return value of that to a variable.  For example, `str = str.replace("&", "&#38")`.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons StringUtils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEachRepeatedly-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-

I'd use StringUtils like this (Libraries are our friends):

```
String [] originalLetters = {"A", "B", "a", "b"};
String [] mappings = {"123", "456", "789", "091"};
String str = "A quick BROWN Fox jumps over the Lazy Dog";
String output = StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(str, originalLetters, mappings);
```

Hope that helps... caveat - I've not tried compiling this.